# FORTRAN graphic library on Linux

Tags: linux, graph, fortran

I started learning FORTRAN and need graphic library to plot output
As I'm not familiar with FORTRAN environment, I wanted to ask for recommendation

I'm used to matplotlib, and preferably looking for something similar. Similar in means of available features, and workflow concepts

Searching through Synaptic it seems like PGPLOT is the way to go

PS I know I could wrap FORTRAN code in Python in different ways

Comment: What is the reason you want to plot straight from your Fortran code?

Comment: Right now just general graphic package to plot intermediate data products. If I do well then perhaps I'll look for package that handles large data sets. But if I get there I'll probably know what to use till then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used PGPLOT, dislin and PLPLOT.   In this era I'd use dislin or PLPLOT.   PGPLOT was last updated in 2001 and only has a FORTRAN 77 interface, which can be used with Fortran 90/95/2003 but the compiler won't be able to check that your calls have the correct arguments.   The other two have Fortran 95 interfaces.   Of dislin and PLPLOT, I think dislin to be better documented.  dislin also provides widgets for GUI input.   dislin is free for some uses; for business uses one is supposed to purchase a license.  PLPLOT is open source under the LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PGPLOT is an option.

You may also want to look into PLplot: http://plplot.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

[DISLIN](http://www.dislin.com/) - supports several platforms and languages (python included).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/) or similar software? VisIt can visualise *very* large datasets and has a mechanism for *in-situ visualization* with the `libsim`  library. See this presentation for a nice introduction to in-situ visualization with VisIt: http://calcul.math.cnrs.fr/Documents/Ecoles/Data-2011/CouplageSimulationVisualization.pdf.

See [here](http://visitusers.org/index.php?title=Simulation_Control_Interface) for the `libsim` api.

Finally, a few additional notes.

- While you sate

> I'm used to matplotlib, and preferably looking for something similar.
>   Similar in means of available features, and workflow concepts

using `libsim`would be quite different, but it is very powerful.

- and

> Right now just general graphic package to plot intermediate data
>   products. If I do well then perhaps I'll look for package that handles
>   large data sets. But if I get there I'll probably know what to use
>   till then.

Rather than write a solution now and then change it to deal with large data sets, why not just write a scalable solution now?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with FORTRAN plotting but in most languages a quick way to do easy-to-program static graphics is not to use a library at all but to find that language's equivalent of the C "system()" call, find a program that will do the plotting and write the equivalent of:

```
1. Write plot data to file.
2. Do system call running plot program with data file argument.
3. [Optional] Delete plot data file.
```

This gives your program the full functionality of the plot program with minimal programming. The plot data and plot program are likely to be in the disk cache so it's all in memory. It's also easily debugged.

People underestimate the system() call - it gives access to a vast array of functionality including scripting. Some would say it's not efficient or "pure" but the user won't care and it will often drastically reduce the amount of programming necessary. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- PLplot: http://plplot.sourceforge.net/
- gtk-fortran. It is a GTK / Fortran binding which offers also an interface to PLplot: https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran/wiki